# SmoothState.js Show Current Page Until Next Is Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, transition, smoothstate.js

I am using smoothstate.js on WordPress and I'm trying to figure out how to keep the current page active until the next is fully loaded: so the new page will display behind as the current page is exiting. Here's an example: http://springsummer.dk/

Here is my code:

```
(function($) {
'use strict';
var $page = $('#main'),
    options = {
        debug: true,
        prefetch: true,
        cacheLength: 10,
        onStart: {
            duration: 1000, // Duration of our animation
            render: function ($container) {
                // Add your CSS animation reversing class
                $container.addClass('is-exiting');
                // Restart your animation
                smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
            }
        },
        onReady: {
            duration: 0,
            render: function ($container, $newContent) {
                // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
                $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
                // Inject the new content
                $container.html($newContent);
            }
        },
        onAfter: function ($container) {
            $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
        }
    },
    smoothState = $page.smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to clone the current page in a temporary wrapper.